# Are there anyway I can run commands through `docker-compose`, like instantiate containers, run commands, stop containers?

Tags: unit-testing, docker, docker-compose, odoo

I suppose the title says it all.

The case is that I want to run a set of Odoo Unit Tests. What I have in mind is:

1. Run `docker-compose up -d --build`
2. Run the Odoo Unit Tests
3. Stop all running containers from point number 1

Aside from making a shell script that runs these commands (commands to run Odoo Unit Tests), are there any more practical methods?

Answer (score 0):

#### init containers

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

#### run tests

```
container_id=$(docker ps | grep image_name | awk '{print $1}')

docker exec -it $container_id bash -c 'cmd to run unit tests'
```

#### shutdown containers

```
docker-compose down
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker-compose run -command to run Odoo tests. E.g.:

```
docker-compose run yourodooservice \
  --test-enable \
  --stop-after-init \
  -d yourdatabase \
  -i your_module
```

You can find more info for run parameters and restrictions from documentation at https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/.

Good article about Odoo testing can be found at https://link.medium.com/TNN7jLbUoY. It also includes considerations when using docker and docker-compose.

I normally prefer running tests with pure docker, not with docker-compose. I find it easier to manage the dependencies that way. If compose fits better to your test and development workflow, I can see this also as a valid choise.